# how to Hide XNA 4.0?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm Trying to hide my XNA game window but i don't seem to be able to here's what I've tried so far from what i could get off google.

```
        Form frmXNA = (Form)Form.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
        frmXNA.Hide();
```

I have also tried

```
        Form frmXNA = (Form)Form.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
        frmXNA.Visible = false;
```

I figure I'm doing something very simple wrong and once it's pointed out I'll probably laugh at how i didn't see it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Why are you trying to hide the window? An XNA app would theoretically only have a single window.

Comment: @Tejs _"An XNA app would theoretically only have a single window"_ - OP is trying to _hide_ the game window, **not** _create multiple_ windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the System.Windows.Form refrence to the project and then add the using statment:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and then add this in the Initialize method:

```
Form MyGameForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
            MyGameForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

EDIT:
mybee the playing with the opacity

```
 Form MyGameForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
        MyGameForm.Opacity = 0;
```

Comment: That would only hide the boarder, i need to make everything invisible

Comment: Thank you Worked perfect, like i said, probably something easy I hadn't thought of :)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the `form.Hide()` function, you just need to call it **after** the form window is shown.

Here is a sample, which hides the window only the first time it is drawn.

```
Form window = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
window.Shown += (e, s) => window.Hide();
```

Comment: This is the actual answer to the OP's question. I've tried it and it works.