# How to make a XNA window close without shutting down the game

Tags: c#, xna

I am making a game that has a main home screen (that is a windows form) and i need some code that will just close the xna window but not the form.

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find an answer. I figured out how to *open the form*, I just need to *close the opened xna window* so just my **main menu** is there and i can start **another** xna game.

Comment: Cast it to a System.Windows.Forms.Form window and form.Minimize() it. Or form.Visible = false

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Hide XNA 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539031/how-to-hide-xna-4-0)

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539031/how-to-hide-xna-4-0). Essentially, you will need to modify the opacity to hide the game window. The game will still be active.

***Edit***

*my game continues to run in the backgound and so on my main menu i can't start another instance of that game*

If you need to completely close the XNA game, the game will need to be launched from the Windows Form application. In your Windows Form application you can use:

```
Game1 myGame = new Game1();
myGame.Run();
```

to run the XNA game. Then when you use `Game.Exit()` (in the XNA application) to close the game, the main menu should still be open in the background.

Comment: my game continues to run in the backgound and so on my main menu i can't start another instance of that game